# changing background color in peoplesoft using stylesheet

Tags: stylesheet, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am trying to change the background of the tabs using stylesheet in peoplesoft.
But it is not reflecting the changes. The color (dark blue) is not retaining on the pages.
This has to be done in order to change the default background color (light blue) of the tabs to a dark blue color as per the client requirements. 
I tried changing the color referred to the stylesheet using App designer but it is not working.

I have tried changing the style classes in P1_PTSTYLEDEF_SWAN, to change the background of the tabs but it is not reflecting any change.

Pls suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Page tabs are built using a combination of CSS styles and images (for the curved corners). [PeopleBooks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41509_01/pt852pbh2/eng/psbooks/tapd/htm/tapd18.htm#g80251ce4213ea4e8_5c7850_120ce2eb1f1__7b44) explains how to change them. (That link is for PT 8.52, but should be equally applicable to all versions from 8.50 to 8.53. If you're developing on an older version, look up the corresponding PeopleBooks, though [this link for PT 8.49](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tapd/htm/tapd17.htm#g037ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__746b) should apply to all older versions.)

Answer (score 0):

To reflect your changes You may also need to clear cache and bounce the web server in Certain PeopleTools versions... till PT8.52